# Make component detect change in Input

Tags: angular

The situation is:
I have an angular form:

```html
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit) = search(f) novalidate >
  <input name="inputCustomerId" [(ngModel)]="customerId" type= "number">
  <a type="button" (click)="search(f)">Search</a>
</form>
<app-graph *ngIF="customerId" [nodeName]="customerId"></app-graph>
```

And in the .ts file:

```
export class C implements OnInit{
  customerId: any; 
  constructor(){}
  ngOnInit(){}
}
search(form:ngForm){
  if(form.valid){
    this.customerId = form.value.inputCustomerId;
  }
}
```

The Problem is when clicking the button the app-graph component doesn't detect the input change.
How can I make it reload or update data?

Comment: Does  component have `ChangeDetection.onPush`?
Is form valid when you click on button?

Comment: yes I do console.log(this.customerId) after the if and it shows the change but the app-graph component doesn't detect it.

Comment: can you please explain ChangeDetection.onPush with Input() please.
@yuriy

Comment: May be the reason `app-graph` doesn't show up is because `*ngIF="customerId"` was not written correctly? Should be `*ngIf="propertyToCheck"`.


Or when you assign  `this.customer=form.value.inputCustomerId;` `form.value.inputCustomerId` has falsy value so `*ngIf` doesn't show the component

Comment: No it does show but only the first time, even though the search function updates customerId

Comment: search function can't update `customerId` because `form.value.inputCustomerId` is hold the same value as you type in input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to implement ngOnChanges() method in the child component "app-graph".
So the code is:

```js
export class GraphComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input()
  private nodeName : any; 
 
  constructor(){}
  ngOnInit(){}

  ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log("Previous nodeName: ",changes.nodeName.previousValue);
    this.myLogic(changes.nodeName.currentValue);
  }
  
  myLogic(nodeName: any){
    console.log(nodeName);
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is the following

Parent Component

- --Child Component 1
- --Child Component 2

Your `customerId` belongs to child Component 1. Angular will not transfer that state automaticaly to child component 2.

It will initialy load both components with the initial state but changes will not be transfered across components.

In that case you need to make an `Output` with `EventEmitter` from Child Component 1.
And your child Component 2 will have to listen for those changes.

If you need more help to implement those changes, update your answer with all components